# How to solve socket.error: [Errno 10061] in Python with server and my computer

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, communication

I want to make a TCP communication between my computer and server (ubuntu).

The server IP is 203.246.114.176 and its port 30000 is open.

The server is running the following server.py:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 30000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

And my computer has client.py:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('203.246.114.176', 30000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)

try:

    # Send data
    message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
    sock.sendall(message)

    # Look for the response
    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)

    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = sock.recv(16)
        amount_received += len(data)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

When I run at the server, the output is like this:

```
starting up on localhost port 30000
waiting for a connection
```

and the ufw status is like this:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
5979/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5901                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5978/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5980/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
31415                      ALLOW       Anywhere
5981                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5982                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5983                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5984                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5985                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
2222/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
77/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
30000/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
30001/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
30002/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
30003/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
30004/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
30005/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
30006/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
30007/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5979/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5901 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5978/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5980/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
31415 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5981 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5982 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5983 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5984 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5985 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2222/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
77/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30000/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30001/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30002/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30003/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30004/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30005/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30006/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30007/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But my computer shows this output:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\notepad>python client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061]
```

What is the matter? And what should I do?

help plz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in server in this line:

```
server_address = ('localhost', 30000)
```

`localhost` is usually `127.0.0.1`, so You are not binding it to `203.246.114.176` as You think. Try using

```
server_address = ('203.246.114.176', 30000)
```

for this exact IP address, or

```
server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 30000)
```

to listen on all active interfaces.